# Using SQL aggregate results as condition in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to resolve the issue with SQL query where I have next columns:
ITEM NUMBER and CROSS_REFFERENCE. ITEM NUMBER can have multiple values of CROSS_REFFERENCE and what I need is to count them which i can do by grouping by and count by expression. But another thing that i need is statement that say, if the ITEM NUMBER has more than one CROSS_REFFERENCE than return MULTI, otherwise return the single value of CROSS_REFFERENCE that is tied to ITEM NUMBER. 
I tried to usex this expression as new coulmn:

```
MFG: IIf(Count([CROSS_REFERENCE])>1,"MULTI",[CROSS_REFERENCE])
```

But when my results returns i dont get unique list of ITEM NUMBER with ether MULTI, or value for CROSS_REFERENCE.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

[image: Query design]

```
SELECT 
tbl_MFG_XREF.[ITEM NUMBER], 
tbl_MFG_XREF.CROSS_REFERENCE, 
Count(tbl_MFG_XREF.CROSS_REFERENCE) AS CountOfCROSS_REFERENCE, 
IIf(Count([CROSS_REFERENCE])>1,"MULTI",[CROSS_REFERENCE]) AS MFG
FROM 
tbl_MFG_XREF
GROUP BY 
tbl_MFG_XREF.[ITEM NUMBER], tbl_MFG_XREF.CROSS_REFERENCE;
```

Comment: never gonna happen like that. `count()` is an aggregate function, and its results are not available at the row level. count() only has a usable value when ALL rows have been processed/considered. you cannot use count() for filtering at the row level, because its results won't be available until much later - sql servers cannot time travel.

Comment: Also, if you want to count CROSS_REFERENCE, you must remove `tbl_MFG_XREF.CROSS_REFERENCE` from both the SELECT and the GROUP BY clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a base query:

```
SELECT 
  [ITEM NUMBER], 
  Count(CROSS_REFERENCE) AS CountOfCROSS_REFERENCE,
  First(CROSS_REFERENCE) AS FirstCROSS_REFERENCE
FROM 
  tbl_MFG_XREF
GROUP BY 
  tbl_MFG_XREF.[ITEM NUMBER];
```

Instead of `First` you can also use Last or Min or Max. `FirstCROSS_REFERENCE` will only be used if there is only one CROSS_REFERENCE for an item.

Save this query as e.g. `qryItemCountCrossref`

And a second query that uses it as input, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  [ITEM NUMBER], 
  CountOfCROSS_REFERENCE, 
  IIf(CountOfCROSS_REFERENCE > 1, "MULTI", FirstCROSS_REFERENCE) AS MFG
FROM qryItemCountCrossref
```